# Is it possible for a variable to reference itself

Tags: php, variables, this, instance, self

I've never seen something like this in a language, but I'm working with a PHP array and it would quite useful, but more than any thing, I'm curious.

Is it possible for a regular variable to reference itself. For example:

```
    $variable_array = array(1, 2);
    $variable_array = array_merge(self, array(3, 4));
```

or

```
    $variable_string = 'This is a string';
    $variable_string = explode(' ', self);
```

Where `self` is the variable itself, like `this` is when working with objects. Now, I know someone is going to ask why not just call the variable again, and that is what I normally do in this case. However, for readability when dealing with long names, such as named indexes in arrays, this would be useful.

Does PHP, or any language at all do this or something similar?

Comment: How is it going to reference itself if it hasn't been set yet? Isn't that the whole point of a variable?

Comment: nope. not possible. just do `$var = explode(' ', $var)` and move on. You **CAN** make a self-referential variable. e.g. `$a = 'foo'; $a = &$a; echo $a;` will output `foo`, but it's pretty useless.

Comment: I think that's like what happens when you put a black hole inside another black hole

Comment: Why/How should e.g. `explode()` even know the variable in the first place? The function doesn't need to know …

Comment: @nietonfir `eplode()` needs to know what it is exploding, so a variable is passed.

Comment: @sbeliv01 I've edited it because it wasn't clear that this is for when you assign a variable the return value of a function that takes the variable as a parameter. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ray What do you mean by this? I don't understand. You assign variables to themselves after changing the value of the variable all the time.

Comment: "Where self is the variable itself, like this is when working with objects" `$this` has scope (object). What would the scope of `self` be? statement? What would `$a = $b = f(self);` yield? And what if none of those variables have been initialized yet? Things become far *less* readable IMO.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073945/can-a-reference-variable-in-php-be-used-to-as-an-alias-for-long-variable-names?rq=1

Comment: @webbiedave, I see where you are going, logically. In my case, the scope is always the statement, and the statement is a straight $a = f();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to RandomSeed reminding me of variable references, I came up with what I think is the closest solution I'm likely to get.

Take this as an example:

```
   $array['index1']['index2']['index3']['index4'];
   $array['index1']['index2']['index3']['index4'] = array_merge(
         $array['index1']['index2']['index3']['index4'], 
         array('test' => 'answer'),
         array('test2' => 'answer'));
```

This is unappealing in my eyes, and a bit difficult to follow, especially if there are multiple of these on a page, or in a controller action.

So this is an alternative:

```
   $self = &$array['index1']['index2']['index3']['index4'];
   $array['index1']['index2']['index3']['index4'] = array_merge(
         $self, 
         array('test' => 'answer'),
         array('test2' => 'answer'));
```

A Quick test on my live environment seems to verify that it works.

Comment: Because you have already created a reference to the array element, your second statement does not need to repeat the indexes. It could just be `$self = array_merge($self, ...`. I was just thinking the main reason you were interested in this was to avoid repeating the long name.

Comment: @Don't Panic, no you are absolutely right. Mostly I'm concerned with line length and what is on the right side of the `=`, so I personally would leave the left variable the same to make it ready to scan for others.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible for a regular variable to reference itself

No (in the way you go on to describe it), it is not. Nothing will be more clear than using the identifier (the variable name). That's exactly what it's for.

```
$variable_array = array_merge($variable_array, array(3, 4));
```

Imagine:

```
$a = $b = f(self);
```

We could come up with a rule to handle this but why bother when we can make it ultimately clear with:

```
$a = $b = f($a);
```

> readability when dealing with long names, such as named indexes in arrays

You may be thinking of Visual Basic's [`With`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)

PHP does not have an elegant equivalent. You could just:

```
$shortName = $veryLongName['with']['many']['indexes'];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working with specific array names and tree structures that can't practically be altered or replaced with shortnames. Otherwise, that is the standard procedure.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your headline question is [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414936/is-it-possible-for-a-variable-to-reference-itself#comment39645581_25414936): `$a = &$a;`. But that's not what you really wanted to ask.

In fact, you are precisely expecting the features of an object:

> assign a variable the return value of a function that takes the variable as a parameter

```
$object->modify(); // no parameter, no assignation
```

Alternatively, you might be looking for a function that takes a parameter as a reference:

```
function foo(&$bar) {
    $bar = 'buzzle';
}

$qux = 'fizz';
foo($qux);
echo $qux; // output: "buzzle"
```

Nothing else.

Comment: This actually indirectly gave me my answer. It never occurred to me to create a `$self = &$array` call `$self` and do whatever to it, then pass my initial array, which is now modified. There are probably a dozen reasons to avoid this, but it is something for the toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing reason you are interested in this is

> "...for readability when dealing with long names, such as named indexes in arrays..."

Then, considering you are going to have to type out the long name at least once anyway, I suppose you could just create a short named reference to the long named thing and use that.

```
$short = &$for_example['really']['long']['names']['like']['this'];
$short = explode(' ', $short); // etc.
```

But this seems like it might end up creating more confusion than it would be worth.

Comment: You're right. I'm working with arrays as data trees, so I'm ultimately just adding more indexes to the short name, then renaming them to the short name again.